# Forwarding events/commands when using Xamarin.Forms Custom Renderer

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms app I want to customise the look and feel of buttons to a higher degree than allowed so I am using a custom renderer to replace the default control in Xamarin.Forms on Windows Phone 8.1 with my own button control.

My control that just extends Button, will add extra properties later.

```
public class ButtonControl : Button {}
```

My custom renderer on Windows Phone 8.1:

```
public class ButtonControlRenderer : ViewRenderer<ButtonControl, Button>
  {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ButtonControl> e)
    {
      base.OnElementChanged(e);

      if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        return;

      var button = new Button
      {
        Style = Application.Current.Resources["ButtonWithTilt"] as Style,
        Content = Element.Text,
        IsEnabled = Element.IsEnabled
      };

      Element.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;

      SetNativeControl(button);
    }
  }
```

And, how I'm using the control in the Xamarin.Forms XAML file:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                         HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                         Margin="24,12,24,0">
              <controls:ButtonControl Text="{res:Translate LoginPageButtonText}"
                      TextColor="{x:Static const:Colours.OverlayColor}"
                      BackgroundColor="{x:Static const:Colours.PrimaryColor}"
                      BorderWidth="0"
                      Margin="0,24,0,0"
                      HeightRequest="50"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding LoginValid}"
                      Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
                      StyleId="{x:Static const:StyleIds.LoginPageButton}"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

As I'm replacing the button, my commands don't work out of the box, I have to add the following into OnElementChanged so that when my new button is clicked the command is exeuted:

```
button.Tapped += delegate
      {
        Element.Command.Execute(null);
      };
```

This doesn't seem like the cleanest solution, is there a better way of hooking this up?

Also, if there was an event I wanted to trigger on the base Xamarin.Forms control, like Clicked, how would I go about this? Would I override the Clicked event in my ButtonControl than inherits from the Button class and add a method to trigger the event from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`button.Tapped += handler` is the way you do it. But instead of executing the command, you only have to call `SendClicked()` on your Element. This will execute the command **and** trigger the `Clicked` event. The standard renderers are doing the same.

You should transform the anonymous delegate to a method in your class, to be able deregister the event on cleanup, to prevent memory leaks.

```cs
public class ButtonControlRenderer : ViewRenderer<ButtonControl, Button>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ButtonControl> e)
    {
        //your creation code ...            
        button.Tapped += OnButtonTapped;
    }

    private void OnButtonTapped(...)
    {
        ((IButtonController)Element)?.SendClicked();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (Control != null)
            Control.Tapped -= OnButtonTapped;

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much, looked for a method but wasn't casting to IButtonController so never found it.
Good tip about disposing!